# Remove white space in Wordpress home screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress child theme and I'm a bit frustrated at the excess white space between my image slider and footer. I've tried editing the style sheet in a few different ways

```
footer {
    margin-top:-10px; 
    padding-top:-100px;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid {
margin-bottom: 0 !important;
margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

I see in the inspect element that it's this `<section class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid block">`. I'm confused about how to eliminate this white space.

Here's an image of what it looks like (my site isn't live yet) https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZU3q.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your source. Have you tried adjusting bottom padding like so?

```
.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```